# changing row values of pandas from dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where i need to change row values if it is present in a dictionary like this:

```
dict = {"A":Apple:"B":Ball,"C":Cat}

        c1          c2      c3
0       A          Tree     GH
1       B          Train    GC
2       C          Yarn     GR
```

I want the column c1 values to be changed from the dict if it is present.

Comment: `df.c1.map(dict)` ?

Comment: Or, `df.replace({'c1': ddict})`

Comment: You're dict is invalid for replacement, you need to make the values strings also with quotes. Use: `dict = {"A":"Apple","B":"Ball","C":"Cat"}`